# Can Android custom launcher change the behavior of the apps it may run?

Tags: android, android-intent

Can Android custom launcher change the behavior of the apps it may run?
Can it access their ClassLoader?
Any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can it access their ClassLoader?

No. First, the apps are in separate processes. Second, allowing an app the ability to affect another app's `ClassLoader` would be a major security hole.